Problem uploading images with Dropzone nodejs and nuxt 3
I'm waiting for the image to be loaded from req.file but it didn't write the database path.
This is my router:
bookRoute
router.post('/upload', authMiddleware.authenticateUser, upload.single('image'), bookController.uploadFile);

router
   .route('/uploader')
   .get(authMiddleware.authenticateUser, bookController.getBooksByUploader);

This is my controller:
bookController
const uploadFile = async (req, res) => {
   try {
      if (!req.file) {
         return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file uploaded' });
      }

      const filePath = req.file.path;
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'File uploaded successfully', filePath });
   } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading file', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server ERROR' });
   }
};


const store = async (req, res) => {
   try {
      const { name, author, description, page, image } = req.body;
      const uploader = req.user._id;

      const existingBook = await Book.findOne({ name, author });

      if (existingBook) {
         return res.status(400).json({ error: 'A book with same name and author already exist!' });
      };

      // const image = req.file ? req.file.path : null;
      console.log('Image path:', image || 'No file');

      const newBook = await Book.create({
         name,
         author,
         description,
         page,
         uploader,
         image
      });

      return res.status(201).json({
         message: 'Book created successfully',
         books: newBook
      });

   } catch (error) {
      // Handle validation errors
      if (error.name === 'ValidationError') {
         if (checkValidationErrors(error, res)) return;
      } else {
         console.error("Error at creating book", error);
         return res
            .status(500)
            .json({ error: 'Internal Server ERROR' });
      }
   }
};

This is my template part on the Nuxt 3
onMounted(() => {
  if (dropzoneElement.value) {
    dropzone = new Dropzone(dropzoneElement.value, {
      url: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/books/upload",
      thumbnailWidth: 150,
      maxFilesize: 2, // Max file size in MB
      dictDefaultMessage: "Drag files here or click to upload",
      paramName: "image", // Param name should match with multer's expected field name
      acceptedFiles: "image/*",
      autoProcessQueue: false, // Disable automatic file uploads
      init: function () {
        this.on("sending", (file, xhr, formData) => {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${authStore.token}`);

          // formData.append("name", newBook.name);
          // formData.append("author", newBook.author);
          // formData.append("description", newBook.description);
          // formData.append("page", newBook.page);
        });

        this.on("success", (file, response) => {
          // Handle success
          console.log("File uploaded successfully", response);
          newBook.image = response.filePath;
        });

        this.on("error", (file, message) => {
          // Handle error
          console.error("Upload failed:", message);
        });
      },
    });
  }
});

const addBook = async () => {
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dropzone.on("complete", (file) => {
        if (file.status === 'success') {
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject(new Error("File upload failed"));
        }
      });

      dropzone.processQueue();
    });

    await bookStore.addBook(newBook);

    currentPage.value = 1;
    modal?.hide();
    Object.assign(newBook, {
      name: "",
      author: "",
      description: "",
      page: null,
      image: null,
      editedBookId: null,
    });

    await bookStore.fetchBooksByUploader();

    showToast("New book added successfully", {
      type: "success",
      position: "top-right",
      timeout: 1000,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    showToast("Failed to add book", {
      type: "error",
      position: "top-right",
      timeout: 3000,
    });
  }
};

I did this but I didn't want to take a picture
const { name, author, description, page, image } = req.body;

It seems like it should be saved with req.file instead, right?
I'm waiting for the image to be loaded from req.file but it didn't write the database path.

I feel like this question is very much the same and doesn't deserve another question.

@kissu What about the answer?
